# Switching from Trac to Phabricator

Tags: trac, phabricator

We're currently looking into switching from Trac to Phabricator and I was wondering if anyone could share their experience transfering the wikis and tickets they had on Trac.

I've looked into Conduit and I suppose making a script getting Trac's info with XMLRPC and pushing them in Phabricator would work. What's missing is I haven't found a method to create a Wiki page or add comments to an existing task.

If anyone has an idea on how this could be achieved it would help greatly.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's a while since we migrated away from Trac to other solutions, but our current migration to Phabricator has dealt with issues from a couple of other similar solutions (Github, JIRA, Redmine) to Phabricator.

From our experiences (so far):

- We haven't used Conduit for wiki pages, so I don't know how well that works (manually moved everything instead - good opportunity to clean up documents).
- You can add comments to tasks with maniphest.update (comments field).

Some of the key obstacles we've encountered:

- Lack of a project/component structure like as most other bug trackers (less of a problem in trac since it is 1 project per instance, unless you are migrating multiple trac instances). I assume this is intended to be handled by the "Projects" object in Phabricator (tagging with multiple objects), but it's not an obvious 1-to-1 mapping. And frankly, the whole "Projects" thing in Phabricator is a bit of a mess right now. The concept is cool, but is also pretty easy to abuse in ways perhaps not intended.
- No way to add dependencies/blocking tasks via Conduit. This is a dealbreaker for some of our migration efforts. They have a task on this at phabricator.com-
- Adding comments via conduit, will add them as the user who is doing the import (not the intended behavior). There is an admin option that can be switched on to allow admins to impersonate other users, though they recommend against it. We haven't used it so far (easier, for the projects we've migrated, to just add the commenting user and date of the comment in the comment text).

Note that unless you preserve this explicitly, you will lose possible relevant information such as the date a task was submitted, etc.

You might want to take a look at Arcyon, which is a little tool which wraps up some of the conduit functionality required for migration in a more script-friendly interface:
https://github.com/bloomberg/phabricator-tools

Comment: Did you look at Maniphest's custom fields? It looks like you can add components as a custom field. https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/custom_fields/

Comment: Yes, but we prefer to have our phabricator installation as "clean" as possible to avoid complications later. Currently, we handle components as additional "projects"; this fits with the development plan AFAIK, as Phacility plan to add "subprojects" later.